# Easiest way to play a video from youtube in my app with swiftui?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to make a video player in my app (with swiftUI) that playes videos from youtube when the user creates a URL string. To practise I have seperated this into a new project to see that it works. But the screen is just black with a play button. Nothing happends when I press the play button or the screen.
This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://youtu.be/Wlf1T5nrO50")!
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           
            VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
                .scaledToFit()
            
        }
}
```

I found another video with how to make embedded youtube videos but then you need to just copy the video ID and my user is not that advanced. I want the user to be able to just copy the URL.

Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 6):

A better Solution I made

```swift
struct YoutubeVideoView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var youtubeVideoID: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        
        WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        
        let path = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(youtubeVideoID)"
        guard let url = URL(string: path) else { return }
        
        uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        uiView.load(.init(url: url))
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be better for the code in updateUIView put into makeUIView? makeUIView is the init function which just call once

Answer (score 0):

A YouTube url is not a valid video URL. You have to either add [youtube's library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) or play it using a WKWebView.

Also check out [this package](https://github.com/SvenTiigi/YouTubePlayerKit), it's awesome!

Using WKWebView:

```
 struct LinkView: View {
    var link: String
    var body: some View {
        WebView(url: URL(string: link.embed)!)
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: URL
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
        return webView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
}
extension String {
    var embed: String {
        var strings = self.components(separatedBy: "/")
        let videoId = strings.last ?? ""
        strings.removeLast()
        let embedURL = strings.joined(separator: "/") + "embed/\(videoId)"
        return embedURL
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
LinkView(link: "https://youtube.com/videoid")
```

Remember, this is a very basic WebView that does not handle errors and loading.

Comment: This was the other code I found that I thought was really good. Only problem is that the user need to know how to find the video ID in order to add videos. It seemed a bit complicated. :-)

But then maybe it is the only solution.
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I updated my answer so you can use any YouTube url!

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried the code but got the error : 
SecondVideoPlayer[1478:29131] [Process] 0x7f83b782c620 - [pageProxyID=5, webPageID=6, PID=1480] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, domain=NSURLErrorDomain, code=-1003